# Apache Flink: Do sinks store items buffered from stream during checkpoint into checkpoint state?

Tags: apache-flink

I'm working on a legacy Flink pipeline and we want to change the implementation of the sink we're using. We are running Flink 1.10 are trying to transition from a BucketingSink to a StreamingFileSink, both are writing ORC to the same destination.
Our pipeline is very simple: we union some kakfa streams into our single sink (no other operators).

During deployment testing I've noticed that when we switch from sink1 to sink2 (and vice versa) we end up with missing kafka messages in the files we're writing (queried via hive/trino). The kafka timestamps for the missing messages align with my deployment so I'm confident it's not some unrelated upstream issue.

My current theory is that during a checkpoint the sinks are buffering messages from the streams as they wait for the all the checkpoint barriers, and those buffered events are captured as part of the checkpoint state for that sink and the kafka sources believe those offsets have been delivered/processed (even though they've not been written to a file, but only exist in the sink's buffer). So when I deploy with a different sink, and start from a checkpoint created using the old sink, those buffered messages are lost. I'm looking for confirmation whether or not these sinks write the buffered events to the checkpoint state and will cause the kafka source to treat them as 'processed' even though they haven't been written to a file.

Our timeline looks something like:

```
┌──────┐  ┌──────┐  ┌──────┐  ┌──────┐  ┌────────┐  ┌──────┐
│Sink1 │  │Sink1 │  │Sink1 │  │Deploy│  │ Resume │  │Sink2 │
│ CP1  │─▶│ CP2  │─▶│ CP3  │─▶│Sink2 │─▶│from CP3│─▶│ CP4  │
└──────┘  └──────┘  └──────┘  └──────┘  └────────┘  └──────┘
```

And we end up with a gap in kafka messages written to the ORC files between "Sink1 CP3" and "Sink2 CP4". So I believe something is advancing the kafka offsets in our kafka sources (though our sources are not changing in any way) so the kafka sources think we've processed those buffered messages already and doesn't send them to Sink2 after we resume from CP3. Stranger still: if I revert back to Sink1 and resume from CP4+, the events missing between CP3 and CP4 are written! And no duplicate events are written so it's not rewinding the kafka sources to old offsets and reprocessing all messages after CP3.

So, am I on the right track and the kafka sources have their offsets advanced for buffered messages? Is there a way to safely transition from 1 sink to the other without losing these narrow slices of kafka messages?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, during checkpoint flink is using state store backend, check out save point feature to avoid missing data
https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/ops/state/savepoints/

What is a Savepoint? How is a Savepoint different from a Checkpoint? #
A Savepoint is a consistent image of the execution state of a streaming job, created via Flink’s checkpointing mechanism. You can use Savepoints to stop-and-resume, fork, or update your Flink jobs. Savepoints consist of two parts: a directory with (typically large) binary files on stable storage (e.g. HDFS, S3, …) and a (relatively small) meta data file. The files on stable storage represent the net data of the job’s execution state image. The meta data file of a Savepoint contains (primarily) pointers to all files on stable storage that are part of the Savepoint, in form of relative paths.

Comment: I've been experimenting with savepoints and it appears that I still end up with missing events when switching sinks. If I take a savepoint, and resume using the same sink I have no missed events. If I take a savepoint and resume using the other sink I have missed events. Savepoints, and checkpoints are behaving the same for me in that it appears some of the events from our kafka sources are "lost" unless using the same sink. This suggests that both checkpoints, and snapshots are associating the buffered events with particular sink implementations.

Comment: I understand, I would try to search for "safe shutdown" where the buffer is fully flushed before getting to a full stop,  in other technology called as "graceful shutdown"

Comment: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=103090212#content/view/103090212

Comment: In TERMINATE, we want the timers to fire, as this will flush out any buffered state associated with timers, e.g. non-fired windows. In this case, we should emit MAX_WATERMARK for event-time timers. For processing time timers, there is not much we can do for now

Comment: I'm definitely open to instrumenting our code to say "on-or-after checkpoint X stop ingesting events and flush the buffers", but I haven't had much time to pursue this approach. I also just noticed that our sinks shared the same UID, so I'm re-running experiments where the UIDs are unique as this collision may be poisoning the results of my experimentation.
Thanks for the confluence link, very interesting reading!