# Apache Flink: migrate from `window(...).apply` to `window(...).redcuce`

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a Flink application that gathers events for a certain amount of time and then sinks them. I used [apply](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/dev/datastream/operators/windows/#windowfunction-legacy) function:

```
      .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.minutes(30)))
      .apply(windowFunction)
```

```
def apply(key: String, window: TimeWindow, input: Iterable[AggEvents], out: Collector[AggEvents]): Unit
```

Now I realized that the [reduce](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/dev/datastream/operators/windows/#reducefunction) function makes a lot more sense:

```
      .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.minutes(30)))
      .reduce(reduceFunction)
```

```
override def reduce(value1: AggEvents, value2: AggEvents): AggEvents
```

The application has been running for quite some time now, question is - will the change break it due to the difference in the snapshot structure?

Comment: A change in the execution plan will make the snapshot incompatible. Since you are sending the results to a sink, why is restarting with fresh state a problem? Maybe you can add that to your question.

Comment: That's what I really wanted to find out, really. Thank you! The state with the events stored for an apply function seemed to be easily convertible to the one required for a reduce function (by just applying reduce function to all the elements). That is why I decided there is a chance. Do you want to create an answer, I would accept it then. Might be useful to other people in the same situation.

Comment: Ok. My comment was very generic. The full answer is "it depends". I have added more details in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any change you make will need to be deployed with a stop and a start. When a Flink project is stopped for deploying a new change, a Snapshot/Savepoint is created. You have the option to restart the application with the last saved snapshot. This is the only way to ensure that the application will resume with in a state as close as possible to the time the application stopped.

While restarting with the previous Savepoint, several rules need to be followed for the state to be restored.

1. If the added/removed operators are stateless (map, filter, etc), it is not an issue.
2. If some stateful operators or topology is changed, the restart with state will fail. The application will need to be restarted without the previous state.
3. The input/output type of operators that write/read to/from stateful operators should not be changed.

There are many more. This [Flink docs link](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.17/docs/ops/upgrading/#application-topology)  is the full list of how a Flink application topology affects the application migration.

if your application has several operators and state resumption is critical, my suggestion is you can test your change with deploying a new version with saved Snapshot. If the application cannot be restored, you can rollback and deploy the previous version with the saved Snapshot.

This question has a more in depth discussion of how the sink's state is restored from Checkpoints.

[Apache Flink: Do sinks store items buffered from stream during checkpoint into checkpoint state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67843744/apache-flink-do-sinks-store-items-buffered-from-stream-during-checkpoint-into-c)

Comment: > can test your change with deploying a new version with saved Snapshot

How can one do that?

Comment: @Skeeve my experience is limited to Flink on AWS Kinesis app. This is how I do it. Stop app (this will save a snapshot) -> deploy the new version -> start app with latest saved snapshot. if there is an error, force stop, redeploy old version and start with the saved snapshot.